# Determining the size of table and blob in Azure Storage Service

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to determine the table size for each table and each blob entity size of my azure storage.

I tried using $MetricsTransactionsBlob, $MetricsTransactionsTable,$MetricsTransactionsQueue Tables and the analytics of storage service but am not able to determine the size of a given table or a given blob.

I have also tried to download cerabata azure management studio but am unable to determine size of table / blob.

Can someone share sample code which can help me to determine the size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as finding the size for a table in Azure Table Storage, there's nothing available out there to the best of my knowledge. This is something you would need to do on your own. You would need to fetch all entities from a table and calculate the size of each entity. You may find this blog post useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/30/how-the-size-of-an-entity-is-caclulated-in-windows-azure-table-storage.aspx

Coming to blob containers, storage analytics provide you this capability to some extent. You can find the total size of blob storage using `$MetricsCapacityBlob` table. More information about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343264.aspx.

You mentioned that you're using Azure Management Studio from Cerebrata. AMS has support for storage analytics so you can explore `$MetricsCapacityBlob` table using the tool itself. Also you can find the size of a blob container by right clicking on the blob container in question and clicking on `Storage Statistics` context menu item. Other alternative from Cerebrata is their **`Azure Management Cmdlets`** product (http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-cmdlets/features). You can use `Get-BlobContainerSize` Cmdlet to find the size and total number of blobs in a blob container.

Comment: new link for calculating azure table storage entity size https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/avkashchauhan/how-the-size-of-an-entity-is-caclulated-in-windows-azure-table-storage